# How to correct java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory) in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to save output of console in parquet file because output is consist of 13849 rows.output to save vector of value 2.484

```
implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A): Seq[A] = { 1 to n map(_ => f) } 
}
val myHis = 13849.times { "2.48489" }
new java.io.PrintWriter("file:///usr/local/spark") { write(myHis.mkString(", ")); close }
```

Exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/usr/local/spark (No such file or
>   directory)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)

how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.PrintWriter` assumes that the file passed as an argument **already exists**, so it will throw an exception if it doesn't. If your file does not exist, then you should call `new java.io.PrintWriter(new File(filepath))` where `filepath` is the absolute path of your file.

Comment: I create new file but data will appear in parquet file.val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("file:///usr/local/sparkloutput.txt" ))
new java.io.PrintWriter("output.txt"){ write(myHis.mkString(", ")); close }.error still

Comment: @SalmaElzeheiry Is your file path format correct? Personally, I've never used *file:///* at the start.

Comment: @SalmaElzeheiry In the line `val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("file:///usr/local/sparkloutput.txt" ))` you create a new file named `sparkloutput.txt` and then you try to `new java.io.PrintWriter("output.txt"){ write(myHis.mkString(", ")); close }`, but does `output.txt` exists? Or maybe you intended it to be `sparkloutput.txt`

Comment: I want to save console in file and save output in parquet file..

Comment: The line `new java.io.PrintWriter("output.txt"){ write(myHis.mkString(", ")); close }` has the same problem I told you in the answer, `PrintWriter` expects `output.txt` to be an existing file so it will give you the same error as before.